# is there Any Dropdown <select> contains checkboxes?

Tags: javascript

I need a dropdown menu `<select>` which contains multiple checkboxes.
so people can drop down and select many options (all the checkboxes should be inside the dropdown)

Sometimes this is called a combobox (just to make everyone understands what I'm looking for)

I want this with javascript/css & not java applet or flash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the thing you're describing - http://code.google.com/p/dropdown-check-list/